# making mathematical conjectures

Tags: soft-question, conjectures, research

If a non-mathematician wanted to conjecture something and had strong numerical evidence to support the conjecture, how would he/she go about doing so? Would the mathematical community

(a) take it seriously?

(b) even look at it?

Comment: Depends. Erdös was very well known for its conjectures, and every single one was taken very seriously. But he also proved some of them, that helped a bit :-) But even a newbie, with something meaningful, would have chances: Ramanujan was once "newbie" (in the sense that he was not known at all in Europe when he presented his revolutionary ideas)

Comment: On the other hand, mathematicians are tired to see cranks giving yet-another-simple-proof-of-Fermat's-last-theorem, I doubt they would look at such a thing.

Comment: If an unknown person would publish a proof, and this proof is in fact brillant and new (even if noone expected it), I wonder if he/she would get the deserved reward.

Comment: @Peter There was a similar case, proportionaly, when [Apéry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roger_Ap%C3%A9ry) proved that $\zeta(3)$ is irrational. He was not very well known at the time.

Comment: If anyone aspires to be taken seriously in anything, (s)he can't just spill out a conjecture and sit down to wait others to appreciate it just like that. The conjecturer (nice word!) will either have to make some work backing up the conjecture's soundness or else get a mathematician friend that understands him/her and can help him to work out the mathematical part of the conjecture

Comment: @arbautjc, I don't think it is a matter of being well- known at all but, as the OP wrote, being *a mathematician* or not. Apéry was a professional mathematician.

Comment: As the OP has mentioned, their particular conjecture has strong numerical evidence to back it up. That gives it far more credibility than a mere statement of a conjecture.

Comment: @arbautjc Of course it's of use. Your example is a perfectly accepted method of proof and can be verified by publishing the code of the program which produced the proof. I'm not sure why you mentioned proof though, as the OP is asking about conjecture. If the difference of two expressions can be shown to be within a small interval about zero by numerical methods, then that is strong numerical evidence that the two expressions may be equal and warrants the statement of the conjecture of their equality.

Comment: Without further precision from the OP, we can make many conjectures about what he has in mind. But I can safely claim these ones are useless: let's just wait for him to tell.

Comment: I don't know if it's a coincidence but I posted one conjecture and got downvoted and the thread is even on hold. Mathematicians have big egos , sense of superiority and entitlement to know and understand everything more than a layman.

Comment: @martin First, read in the literature and see if the conjecture you made doesn't already exist. If it doesn't, then try to contact a mathematician.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with any serious field, there are those in the math community who might take it seriously, and others who wouldn’t. There is also a huge swath of the community for whom it would make little or no difference, and those in that swath might not even ever come across it.

If it's significant — and that can probably best be measured by either having a large potential impact on a small portion of mathematics, or an impact (of any size, really) on a large portion of mathematics — then enough mathematicians will look at it within a reasonable time after its "release" (*e.g.*, publication) to either validate its merit(s) or debunk it. Either way, progress is made.

As for how to go about it, you could "publish" it here on MSE for others to poke at, you could write up a paper yourself and either submit it to a journal or just post to the arXiv, or you could contact another mathematician (preferably one with a knowledge of the specific area of mathematics in question) and see if you can pursue a collaboration.

Comment: thank you for your response - it is nice to have a perspective from someone who does number theory as a hobby - & that you have had experience in collaboration on papers. How did you go about approaching the people you collaborated with?

Comment: I found an expert [relatively-speaking] in the area I was interested in, and emailed him. Actually, I tried that with five different mathematicians before I found one willing to collaborate with me. We now have three published papers together, and are awaiting the final decision (post-revision) on a fourth.

Comment: I notice he has also collaborated with the likes of Jean-Louis Nicolas, which gives you an Erdos number 3 I believe !!

Comment: Yes, that was one of the most excellent side-effects!